# Pivot Rows to Column with SUM if Hours between two Time Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Im using MS SQL Server 2008
Table name is **tblDateTimeLog**:

```
ID INT(AI)
RecordID INT
DateLog DATE  
TimeLog TIME
DetachmentCode INT
EntryDate DATETIME
IsDeleted BIT
UserID VARCHAR(50)
```

I have a table containing this:

```
RecordID | DateLog    | TimeLog
11       | 2013-06-01 | 07:59:00
11       | 2013-06-01 | 19:01:00
11       | 2013-06-02 | 07:57:00
11       | 2013-06-02 | 19:03:00
11       | 2013-06-03 | 07:49:00
11       | 2013-06-03 | 19:11:00
14       | 2013-06-04 | 08:01:00
14       | 2013-06-04 | 19:03:00
14       | 2013-06-05 | 07:52:00
14       | 2013-06-05 | 19:02:00
```

One Record ID can have multiple TimeLog on the same DateLog

Now I want it to show like this:
The Dates as columns and the Total No. of Hours between MIN(TimeLog) and MAX(TimeLog)

```
RecordID | 2013-06-01 | 2013-06-02 | 2013-06-03 | 2013-06-04 | 2013-06-05
11       | 11:02:00   | 11:06:00   | 11:22:00   | NULL       | NULL  
14       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | 11:02:00   | 11:10:00
```

As per Mikael's Answer, this works but as I understand his query, this returns MIN(TimeLog):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnList NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnList = 
STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT ','+QUOTENAME(DateLog)
            FROM TESTPIS.dbo.tblDateTimeLog
            WHERE IsDeleted=0 AND DateLog >= '2013-06-15' AND DateLog <= '2013-06-30'
            ORDER BY 1
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, ''
    )

SET @SQL = 'SELECT P.RecordID, '+@ColumnList+'
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT RecordID, TimeLog, DateLog FROM TESTPIS.dbo.tblDateTimeLog WHERE isDeleted=0
                    ) AS T
                PIVOT
                    (
                        MIN(TimeLog) FOR DateLog IN ('+@ColumnList+')
                    ) as P'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

What I want to return is like `DATEDIFF(MINUTES,MIN(TimeLog),MAX(TimeLog)`

I tried replacing the `MIN(TimeLog)` in the query with this
`SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTES,MIN(TimeLog),MAX(TimeLog))`

However, I got this error
`Incorrect syntax near '('.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select P.RecordID,
       P.[2013-06-01],
       P.[2013-06-02],
       P.[2013-06-03],
       P.[2013-06-04],
       P.[2013-06-05]
from (
     select RecordID,
            TimeLog,
            DateLog
     from YourTable
     ) as T
pivot(min(TimeLog) for DateLog in ([2013-06-01],
                                   [2013-06-02],
                                   [2013-06-03],
                                   [2013-06-04],
                                   [2013-06-05])) as P
```

To build the query dynamically you have to first figure out what the column list should contain.

```
select distinct DateLog
from YourTable
order by 1
```

The result from that query has to be turned into a comma separated list and since numbers like that is invalid column names you can use [quotename()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) to enclose the value in [].

To build the comma separated list of column you can use `for xml path('')`.

```
select stuff((select distinct ','+quotename(DateLog)
              from YourTable
              order by 1
              for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

`stuff()` is there to remove the first comma.

Then you just need to put it all together and execute the query you have built.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
declare @ColumnList nvarchar(max)

select @ColumnList = stuff((select distinct ','+quotename(DateLog)
                            from YourTable
                            order by 1
                            for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @SQL = '
select P.RecordID, '+@ColumnList+'
from (
     select RecordID,
            TimeLog,
            DateLog
     from YourTable
     ) as T
pivot(min(TimeLog) for DateLog in ('+@ColumnList+')) as P'

exec (@SQL)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ad45/1)

**Update**

To get the diff between max and min timelog value for each day you can do a group by on `RecordID` and `DateLog` in the derived table and calculate the diff in seconds between min and max and use that value to calculate a new time value using dateadd.

```
select P.RecordID,
       P.[2013-06-01],
       P.[2013-06-02],
       P.[2013-06-03],
       P.[2013-06-04],
       P.[2013-06-05]
from (
     select RecordID,
            dateadd(second, datediff(second, min(TimeLog), max(TimeLog)), convert(time(0), '00:00')) as TimeDiff,
            DateLog
     from YourTable
     group by RecordID,
              DateLog
     ) as T
pivot(min(TimeDiff) for DateLog in ([2013-06-01],
                                    [2013-06-02],
                                    [2013-06-03],
                                    [2013-06-04],
                                    [2013-06-05])) as P
```

Dynamic version:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
declare @ColumnList nvarchar(max)

select @ColumnList = stuff((select distinct ','+quotename(DateLog)
                            from YourTable
                            order by 1
                            for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @SQL = '
select P.RecordID, '+@ColumnList+'
from (
     select RecordID,
            dateadd(second, datediff(second, min(TimeLog), max(TimeLog)), convert(time(0), ''00:00'')) as TimeDiff,
            DateLog
     from YourTable
     group by RecordID,
              DateLog
     ) as T
pivot(min(TimeDiff) for DateLog in ('+@ColumnList+')) as P'

exec (@SQL)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d226/1)

Comment: @Ruben If you don't know what dates you are looking for then you need to build a [dynamic pivot query](https://www.google.se/search?q=dynamic+pivot+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=dynamic+pivot+site%3Astackoverflow.com&aqs=chrome.0.57.14393j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: I have also been reading Dynamic Pivot Query for quite a while now, but I cant seem to understand the procedure.

Comment: @Ruben Updated answer with some explanations.

Comment: thank you for the wonderful explanation, but this query results to nothing in my table, i have added all the fields from the table if those has something to do with the query.

Comment: @Ruben yes, you can only use the columns from the your table that you actually need. But that would not make your query return nothing. It would make it return too many rows. I have updated the answer with a version that selects the columns you need in a subquery.

Comment: I apologize but I have edited my question, instead of getting the MIN(TimeLog), I want to compute for the total hours between MAX(TimeLog) and MIN(TimeLog). Its like a Daily Time Record.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
        RecordID INT
      , DateLog DATETIME
      , TimeLog TIME
)

INSERT INTO #temp (RecordID, DateLog, TimeLog)
VALUES 
    (11, '2013-06-01', '08:00:00'), (11, '2013-06-02', '09:00:00'),
    (11, '2013-06-03', '10:00:00'), (11, '2013-06-04', '11:00:00'),
    (11, '2013-06-05', '12:00:00'), (14, '2013-06-01', '13:00:00'),
    (14, '2013-06-02', '14:00:00'), (14, '2013-06-03', '15:00:00'),
    (14, '2013-06-04', '16:00:00')

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DateLog, RecordID, tt = CAST(TimeLog AS VARCHAR(8)) 
    FROM #temp
) src
PIVOT (
    MAX(tt) 
    FOR DateLog IN (' + STUFF((
    SELECT ', [' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateLog, 120) + ']'
    FROM #temp
    GROUP BY DateLog
    ORDER BY DateLog
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')
) p'

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

**Output:**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DateLog, RecordID, tt = CAST(TimeLog AS VARCHAR(8)) 
    FROM #temp
) src
PIVOT (
    MAX(tt) 
    FOR DateLog IN ([2013-06-01], [2013-06-02], [2013-06-03], [2013-06-04], [2013-06-05])
) p
```

**Results:**

```
RecordID    2013-06-01 2013-06-02 2013-06-03 2013-06-04 2013-06-05
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
11          08:00:00   09:00:00   10:00:00   11:00:00   12:00:00
14          13:00:00   14:00:00   15:00:00   16:00:00   NULL
```

**Update with results:**

[image: proff]

Comment: @Devard: I am having a different output from your given result.